# In ruby/rails, can you differentiate between no network response vs long-running response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, connection-timeout

We have a Rails app with an integration with box.com. It happens fairly frequently that a request for a box action to our app results in a Passenger process being tied up for right around 15 minutes, and then we get the following exception:

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - SSL_connect
```

Often it's on something that should be fairly quick, such as listing the contents of a small folder, or deleting a single document.

I'm under the impression that these requests never actually got to an open channel, that either at the tcp or ssl levels we got no initial response, or the full handshake/session-setup never completed.

I'd like to get either such condition to timeout quickly, say 15 seconds, but allow for a large file that is successfully transferring to continue.

Is there any way to get TCP or SSL to raise a timeout much sooner when the connection at either of those levels fails to complete setup, but not raise an exception if the session is successfully established and it's just taking a long time to actually transfer the data?

Here is what our current code looks like - we are not tied to doing it this way (and I didn't write this code):

```
def box_delete(uri)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.request_uri)
  http.request(request)
end
```

Comment: There are timeout attributes(`open_timeout`, `read_timeout` and `ssl_timeout`) that you can set to prevent Net::HTTP from waiting for the default timeout, see the docs http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#open_timeout-attribute-method, also your impression that the request never got to an open channel might be wrong because of [slow tcp request](https://code.google.com/p/slowhttptest/wiki/SlowReadTest) unless you dump the traffic you can't really tell

Comment: Thank you, reading the docs now. Your `slow tcp request` link isn't working - is it just dead, or was there a typo?

Comment: issues with google no longer hosting code, alternate link is https://github.com/shekyan/slowhttptest/wiki

Comment: @bjhaid - you may have misunderstood where I'm thinking we never got a connection open - I don't mean our clients sending us requests, I mean us sending requests to the box.com api - those are the ones that seem to either be done quickly, or stick around for almost exactly 15 minutes before timing out. We are definitely not deliberately sending slow requests to box.com. Does that clarify our situation?

Comment: from http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp `tcp_retries2 (integer; default: 15; since Linux 2.2)
The maximum number of times a TCP packet is retransmitted in established state before giving up. The default value is 15, which corresponds to a duration of approximately between 13 to 30 minutes, depending on the retransmission timeout. The RFC 1122 specified minimum limit of 100 seconds is typically deemed too short.` You are probably losing internet connectivity to box.com

Comment: There does not seem to be any way to configure these low-level TCP parameters using Net::HTTP - is that right? 

If you are correct that we are losing internet connectivity to Box.com, do you have any idea why Net::HTTP#read_timeout is not doing it's job? It defaults to 60 seconds. If we aren't getting any data either to them or back from them in 15 minutes, then it must also be the case that we are not reading a block in 60 seconds, so we should be getting an exception for that. See [Net::HTTP#read_timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#read_timeout)

Comment: you need to configure `open_timeout` also `read_timeout` only kicks in after you have established a connection and the server is slow, `open_timeout` will prevent you from waiting for the kernel timeout to establish a connection.